# I am not creating another variable as I expect to

Tags: python, while-loop, counter

I am trying to create a running (moving) total of a value called `var1`.
Thus, I would want it to look like this:

Thus, if `var1 = 5, 4, 3, 12` for the first four values respectively, I want
9 (5+4), 7 (4+3), 15 (3+12) for the TOTAL values etc.

Instead, it is just taking 2 TIMES `var1`, so that the first four values of total are:

`10, 8, 6, 24` etc.

This is the code I am trying. It seems to work (no errors)

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/ameri/tempjohn.csv")
data.total=0
i=1
while i < 3:
data.total+=data.var1
i+=1
print(data.total)
```

can anybody help?
thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

A Pandas dataframe is not a simple Python variable even if you do computations with it: it behaves more or less as a vectorized 2D array.

What happens in your code:

1. you set the column `total` of the dataframe to 0: `data.total` becomes a Series of same lenght as the dataframe containing only 0 values
2. you execute (for `i == 1`) `data.total += data.var1`: as it previously contained 0 values, `data.total` is now a copy of (the Series) `data.var1`
3. you execute (for `i == 2`) `data.total += data.var1`: ok, `data.total` now contains twice the values of `data.var1`
4. end of loop because `3 < 3` is false...

What do to next:

1. read a Pandas tutorial if you want to go that way, but please remember that *Pandas is not Python* and some Pandas objects have different semantics than *standard* Python ones... of forget about Pandas if you only want to learn Python
2. If you really want to do it the Pandas way, the magic word is `shift`: `data.total = data.var1 + data.var1.shift()`